# Scripting the Websphere 7 RAD

Tags: scripting, websphere, ear, ibm-rad

We need to prepare part of our EAR for deployment, we usually do this by loading it into the RAD, right clicking on the EJB and selected "Prepare for deployment" option. Then we export the EAR.

Is there a scripting interface to the IBM RAD 7 application or running the prepare from the command line so we don't have to manually go through the steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ejbdeploy command to generate the deployment code. It's bundled with both RAD and WAS.

See ["Generating EJB deployment code from the command line" at the WAS infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.doc/topics/tegenc.html).

Comment: Unfortunatley it doesn't work correctly with out code which still uses EJB1.
We've discussed this with IBM and it seems that when we update our EJB that we will not need to do this step. Until then we have to use the RAD

Answer (score 0):

You can use RAD's bundled `ejbDeploy` Ant task, described here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.etools.ant.tasks.doc/topics/tantejbd.html

This ends up running exactly the same functionality as "Prepare for deployment", only that it does it in a headless (non-GUI) mode.

(For RAD 8.0 and later, use the `prepForDeploy` task on the enclosing EAR: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/topic/com.ibm.ant.tasks.doc/topics/tpreparefordeploy.html)